# Member Registration Notification Options

Tags: profile-edit, notification

I am using Profile:Edit for new member registration, but because I need to skip the email conformation step, is there a way to notify the new member of their registration, just to let them know they are now registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of add-ons available that will allow a notification email to be sent upon creation of an entry, which is what Profile:Edit does.

Check out [Postmaster](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/postmaster)

Comment: [MX Notify Control](http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-notify-control) is a free option.